# How to create symbolic link relative to the other symbolic link?

Tags: mount, symbolic-link, ln

I have following directory tree

```
/
|-- server
|   |-- cstrike
|   |   |   |-- hltv -> ../../hltv
|   |-- [other files]
|-- 27015
|   |-- hltv
|   |-- server -> ../server
|-- 27016
|   |-- hltv
|   |-- server -> ../server
```

- I want `27015/server` and `27016/server` to be linked to the `/server`.
- Also, I want `27015/server/cstrike/hltv` to be linked to `27015/hltv` and similarly
  `27016/server/cstrike/hltv` to be linked to `27016/hltv`.

As you already may assume `2701{5,6}/server/cstrike/hltv` points to `/hltv` which does not exist.

Could you please advice which tool I should use if not `ln`? `/server` is a directory, not a device, so I guess `mount` is not an option in this case.

Comment: I'd do this with ln. Can I ask why you didn't just try it and see if you could get it working? you can just as easy remove the link again if it fails.

Comment: Does the content of `/27015/hltv` and `/27016/hltv` differ?

Comment: @LPChip I have tried it with `ln` and it did not work. The reason is `/27015/server` symlink resolves in `/server` and therefore all links inside that directory are resolved under `/server` and not `27015/server` as I want it to be. That is why I am here. I need either flag for `ln` or another tool.

Comment: @dodrg Exactly. If they would be the same I would have moved the `hltv` directory to the root.

Comment: @Evgeniy So have a look at the answer of u1686_grawity. I would have suggested it similar: You've to exchange the direction of linking to succeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `/2701x/server` symlinks; create folders in their place; use `mount -o bind` to set up a "bind mount" from `/server` to each `/2701x/server`.

Use `findmnt` to see what mounts you've set up, and make sure to add the mounts to your /etc/fstab so that they stay available after a reboot.

---

Link targets are *always* relative to the "physical" location of the link, not to the "logical" location. In other words, link targets are resolved only after all previous symlinks within the path have been resolved. On the other hand, mounts (including bind mounts) work at a different level and are "invisible" to the symlink resolution code; a bind mount will *look like* the "physical" location.

There is another way to achieve this without bind mounts, however: Invert the layout and have each directory have *its own* `server` directory and its own `server/cstrike/hltv` symlink, while using symlinks only to deduplicate `/2701x/server/[other files]`. For example:

```
/
 ├─27015/
 │  └─server/
 │     ├─cstrike/
 │     │  └─hltv
 │     └─other_stuff -> ../../server/other_stuff
 ├─27016/
 │  └─server/
 │     ├─cstrike/
 │     │  └─hltv
 │     └─other_stuff -> ../../server/other_stuff
 └─server/
    └─other_stuff/
```

Comment: Yes, this feature of symbolic links I have learned yesterday. The second approach would be an option if there were not so many files within `server` dir which is not true. `server` contains all the files needed to run counter strike server and it has dozens of files. But the `mount` is perfectly fine. I can mount `server` in RO mode and `hltv` in write mode. I dunno why I thought that `mount` is suitable only for drives like solid ones or usb sticks. Thank you.